# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: laravel

tengo el siguiente problema: al querer mostrar datos en una vista me esta arrojando este error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'det_ingreso_materials.det_ingreso_material_bodega_id' in 'where clause'

El nombre de la bodega esta relacionado con la tabla det_ingreso_materials mediante el id (id de la tabla bodega y bodega_id en la tabla det_ingreso_materials)

Tengo mi modelo IngresoMaterial:

```
 protected $table='ingreso_materials';

    protected $primaryKey='id';

    protected $fillable=[

        'fecha_ingreso',
        'num_guia_despacho',
        'observaciones',
        'usuario_id',
        'proveedor_id',
        'servicio_id'
    ];

    //traemos los detalles segun el id de la asignacion de material
    public function detalles(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\DetAsignacionMaterial', 'asignacion_material_id', 'id');
    }

     //traemos los materiales asociados
    public function materiales(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Material', 'material_id', 'id');
    }

    //traemos el servicio asociado al material
    public function servicio(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Servicio','servicio_id','id');
    }

    //traemos al proveedor del material
    public function proveedor(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Proveedor','proveedor_id','id');
    }

    public function det_ingreso_bodegas(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\DetIngresoMaterial','det_ingreso_material_bodega_id','id');
    }

    //1 bodega de origen para
    public function bodegas(){
             return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Bodega','bodega_id','id');
    }

    public function det_ingreso_materials(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\DetIngresoMaterial');
    }

    public function det_asignacion_material()
{
    // laravel assumes user_id as foreign and local key.
    //return $this->hasMany('App\File');
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\DetAsignacionMaterial');//, 'material_id', 'id'
}
```

y mi modelo DetIngresoMaterial:

```
 protected $table='det_ingreso_materials';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable=[
        'cantidad',
        'material_id',
        'ingreso_material_id',
        'bodega_id'
    ];

    protected $guarded =[];


     //public function det_transferencia_bodegas(){
       //  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\DetTransferenciaBodega','transferencia_bodega_id','id');
     //}


     public function bodegas(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Bodega');
     }



    public function materiales(){
        //return $this->belongsToMany(Material::class, 'det_transferencia_bodegas', 'bodega_id', 'transferencia_bodega_id');
        //return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Material');//, 'material_id'
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Material','material_id','id');

    }

    public function ingresos(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\IngresoMaterial');
    }
}
```

lo que intento traer es el nombre_bodega en mi vista:

```
     <option value=""> {{ $ingreso->det_ingreso_bodegas[0]->bodegas->nombre_bodega }}</option>
```

y el controlador lo tengo asi:

```
public function detIngresoParaSeriado($id){

        $ingreso = IngresoMaterial::with('det_ingreso_materials')->findOrFail($id);
        $detalle = DetIngresoMaterial::all()->where('ingreso_material_id','=',$id);

        return view('bodega.logistica.detIngresoSeriado', compact('ingreso','detalle'));
    }
```

Puedo mostrar los datos de $ingreso ({{ $ingreso->servicio->servicio }}) y menos $detalle->nombre_bodega que es el que me causa el problema.

Saludos a  todos

Comment: Nos ayudaría indiques cual de las consultas es la que usas y nos muestres como usas los resultados de la misma para saber mas del error

Comment: @BetaM añadi un ejemplo de como muestro los demas campos ademas de indicar la relacion de la bodega con eld etalle de ingreso, la consulta que uso es la que esta en el controlador

Answer (score 0):

En la relación del modelo `IngresoMaterial` tu indicas que hay un campo "det_ingreso_material_bodega_id" que es la llave foranea:

```
    public function det_ingreso_bodegas(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\DetIngresoMaterial','det_ingreso_material_bodega_id','id');
    }
```

Pero revisando tu modelo `DetIngresoMaterial`, efectivamente no existe ese campo:

```
    protected $fillable=[
        'cantidad',
        'material_id',
        'ingreso_material_id',
        'bodega_id'
    ];
```

La relacion debería ser algo asi en el modelo `IngresoMaterial`:

```
    public function det_ingreso_bodegas(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\DetIngresoMaterial','bodega_id','id');
    }
```

Comment: Hola que tal, si, no me di cuenta que estaba pasandole un campo errado, ahora cuando intento recuperar el nombre de esta manera:  <option value=""> {{ $ingreso->det_ingreso_bodegas[0]->nombre_bodega }}</option> no muestra nada, al igual que al intentar recuperar el id del material tampoco muestra nada